# Jackson does not work in jersey

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jersey, jackson

Exception :-

```
Jun 29, 2015 10:32:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [idnsRulesServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.isEnabled(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig$Feature;)Z
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:506)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
```

i am using jersey 1.17 and jackson 1.9.0,jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13 and apache tomcat8.
kindly some one help me reslove this , thank you

my screen is shows to my jars.

[image]

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` means you `jackson` jar with class `SerializationConfig` doesn't contain method `isEnabled` change your jar file

Comment: @Vick Thakor, Thank you sir , But which jar i suppose to use sir

Comment: No , i am using Tomcat8 sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` often means a mixing of incompatible versions. Take out all the Jackson related jars/dependencies you have and use the below

With Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Without Maven (Note: all the jars below are pulled in by `jersey-json` above. All might not be required for basic functionality, but I would include them anyway)

[image]

You may already have some, as they are Jersey jars. So just ignore those.

[Here's a place](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json) You can search for all the jars

Comment: @peesillet still it does not work, i put my screen shot jars i am using in above , please have a look, and kindly help me sir

Comment: Try and get rid of the jersey-media-json-jackson. And if you already didn't, add the POJOMappingFeature init-param seen [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json.pojo.approach.section), into your web.xml. Also get rid of the jackson-all (maybe that is the main problem, i missed that)

Comment: i am unable to understand "rid of the jersey-media-json-jackson", @peeskillet sir

Comment: what i suppose to take out or remove, please explain brief sir

Comment: Remove the two jars from your project... `jersey-media-json-jackson` and `jackson-all`.

Comment: thank you sir, it works sir, thank you very much, i want know more this stuff, where i found resource sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81834/discussion-between-vasantha-raj-and-peeskillet).