# MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: json, eclipse, api, jersey, java-ee-7

[This my controller class. ]

A message body reader for Java class jersey.model.Message, and Java type class jersey.model.Message, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31108432/2587435

Comment: still i am getting the same error . i removed extra/duplicate dependency  and In web.xml, added :   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>

Answer (score 3):

Try it by adding following dependency in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
    <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this works